# Win + Shift + S | Only Works Once?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've been using the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> command to take (and copy) screenshots for ages now.

Since today I ran into the problem that it only works once? The first time (after I've restarted my computer) the snipping tool works fine. But if I try it again to capture another screenshot, nothing is happening.

Things I've tried to solve this issue:

- Turn on the Clipboard History Switch
- Make Sure Snip & Sketch Is Enabled
- Reset Snip & Sketch
- Reinstall Snip & Sketch
- Tried to workaround the issue by creating a macro to make the shortcut for me.
- Tried to run the snipping tool with command 'ms-screenclip:'

Hope someone can provide me with a solution!

Answer (score 2):

DELETE windows snip and sketch period. don't try to download it again it's cursed, keep it deleted, and windows+shift+s works infinitely.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Best advice I have followed this week.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer through a friend of mine.

Turned out that the process 'screen snipping' was still running in the background.

Killed the process and it seems all fine now!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I have the same issue on a fresh Windows 10 installation. Trouble is, after killing the process and re-snipping, the process is stuck again and the annotation options are not coming up, so it's not a working solution.

Comment: @JayVersluis did you eventually found out another solution maybe? This really did the trick for me :)

Comment: I "solved" it by re-installing Windows 

Comment: Killing the process did work exactly once; now `WIN+SHIFT+S` fails again. This [answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/screenclippinghostexe-is-not-working-as-it-should/ffd912c5-bb78-413d-b7cf-4ca4ca8a8d71) might be usefull.